# .Net Portable Class Library and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData

Tags: c#, .net, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using azure MS w/.net backend.  All the POCOs are derived from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData to add the required support for Azure.  However, I want to put all of my POCOs in a PCL (Xamarin.iOS and Android) but I can't seem to find a way to derive POCOs from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData in a cross platform PCL.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Where are you getting the EntityData class from? NuGet? The WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity NuGet package does not have PCLs in it nor does it support iOS nor Android. The EntityData class does not seem to be in the Xamarin Azure Mobile Services component.

Comment: When you download the service backend for an Azure .Net backend, it comes with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Entity reference.  Its not part of Xamarin component and my assumption is that this cannot be done (for now at least).

Comment: Having exactly the same problem. However, i didnt find any workarounds so far. Maybe its not that good idea to store all POCOs in PCL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the **Azure Mobile Services** component in your Xamarin project (http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services/) there is a chance that this class could be already implemented in the component.